# Could not find correct provider above widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am relatively new to Flutter and am building an app that fetches data from an API and display it throughout the app on different widgets. I am using a Provider to perform the API calls and store the deserialized json in a property I then access in the initState function. Below is the widget tree of my main.dart, I want to then access the provider found here in the Dashboard page as this is where the value is required. I know what I am doing is wrong, but how much have I gotten it wrong?

```
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: LoginPage(),
    routes: routes,
  ));
}

class SampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SampleAppState createState() => SampleAppState();
}

class SampleAppState extends State<SampleApp> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> childPages = [
    Page1(),
    Page2(),
    Page3(),
    Page4()
  ];

  void onTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => APIProvider())
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        body: childPages[currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: onTapped,
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          fixedColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.dashboard),
                title: new Text('Page 1'),
                activeIcon: new Icon(
                  Icons.dashboard,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                )),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.list),
                title: new Text('Page 2'),
                activeIcon: new Icon(
                  Icons.list,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                )),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.collections_bookmark),
                title: new Text('Page 3'),
                activeIcon: new Icon(
                  Icons.collections_bookmark,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                )),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.person),
                title: new Text('Page 4'),
                activeIcon: new Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I then attempt to access the provider value in Page1 like so:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    valueFromProvider =
        Provider.of<APIProvider>(context).providerValue;
    super.initState();
  }
```

Perhaps this is happening because the provider value I attempt to access in the Page1 widget is null, would pre-loading my provider solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't providing the Provider at the right time. In your case you add the MultiProvider at page1, but your context is already initialized so you can't access it. In order to properly access it, you must move the MultiProvider to where you initialize the app like the following:

```
runApp(

MaterialApp(
    home: MultiProvider(
    providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => APIProvider())
      ],
     child:LoginPage()
     ),
    routes: routes,
  ));
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: I'll give this a go when I'm back at my machine tomorrow, thanks for the quick turnaround!

Comment: Should I just access the provider directly in the widget where I need the value or is it correct to assign the value to a variable and set it in the initState function?

Comment: No, access the provider directly in the widget. If you are reading a value, it is more efficient to use a Consumer as well.

Comment: Also as a follow up question, do you think that I am over complicating the architecture of my app by using provider to return data from an API call?

Comment: Not at all. I develop complex apps that have a provider for every screen as a view model and each view models consumes providers for different services breaking it up even more. I'd say your level is just the beginning for a basic app. To learn more I'd look at filledstacks.com, he has a lot of great architecture tutorials that really helped me getting started.

Comment: Do you happen to have any sample code you'd be willing to share of the providers set up as view models and populating the widgets with those values? I think that's exactly what I want to do with this app.

Comment: It's hard to give example code as it is more about the architecture. I've thought about writing a turorial, but I've never done anything like that and I really don't have time. I suggest following along with filledstacks's provider v3 arch tutorial. I find his stacked archeticture to be a little overkill at times. Then, implement these practices in your own apps.

Comment: If my answer helped you please upvote as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I have actually just asked another flutter related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63376776/trouble-accessing-localhostportnumber-in-android-emulator), if you could have a look and see if you know the solution that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This helped me enormously! Thanks dude, I appreciate simplicity in code :)